# WARNING: Error setting expression '6578706f7274' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@73e4'

Tags: java, excel, struts2, displaytag

I am using `display-tag` in struts2 to export table into excel sheet. When I download the sheet, it downloads fine but gives this warning:

```
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger warn
WARNING: Error setting expression '6578706f7274' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@17e4898'
ognl.ExpressionSyntaxException: Malformed OGNL expression: 6578706f7274 [ognl.ParseException: Encountered " <INT_LITERAL> "7274 "" at line 1, column 9.
Was expecting one of:
    <EOF> 
    "," ...
    "=" ...
    "?" ...
    "||" ...
    "or" ...
    "&&" ...
    "and" ...
    "|" ...
    "bor" ...
    "^" ...
    "xor" ...
    "&" ...
    "band" ...
    "==" ...
    "eq" ...
    "!=" ...
    "neq" ...
    "<" ...
    "lt" ...
    ">" ...
    "gt" ...
    "<=" ...
    "lte" ...
    ">=" ...
    "gte" ...
    "in" ...
    "not" ...
    "<<" ...
    "shl" ...
    ">>" ...
    "shr" ...
    ">>>" ...
    "ushr" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    "*" ...
    "/" ...
    "%" ...
    "instanceof" ...
    "." ...
    "(" ...
    "[" ...
    <DYNAMIC_SUBSCRIPT> ...
    ]
    at ognl.Ognl.parseExpression(Ognl.java:112)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compile(OgnlUtil.java:241)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setValue(OgnlUtil.java:213)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.trySetValue(OgnlValueStack.java:186)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:173)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setParameter(OgnlValueStack.java:151)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.setParameters(ParametersInterceptor.java:292)
......
......
and so on.....
```

My display table in JSP file is:

```
<display:table class='displayTable' id='orderList' name='orderList' list='orderList' export="true" requestURI="listOrders" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" decorator="com.sanyasi.Decorator.OrderListingDataEntryDecorator">
               <display:setProperty name="export.excel" value="true"/>
                <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="order_details.xls" />

                <display:column title="Action" property="action"></display:column>
                <display:column title="Patient Name" property="patientName"></display:column>
                <display:column title="Patient Phone" property="patientPhone"></display:column>
                <display:column title="Disease" property="disease"></display:column>
                <display:column title="Call Agent" property="callAgent"></display:column>
                <display:column title="Order Status" property="orderStatus"></display:column>
                <display:column title="Delivery Mode" property="deliveryMode"></display:column>
                <display:column title="Delivery Status" property="deliveryStatus"></display:column>
                <display:column title="Delivered By" property="deliveryBy"></display:column>
                <display:column title="Delivery Date" property="deliveryDate"></display:column>
                <display:column title="Details" property="detail"></display:column>
            </display:table>
```

When I click on `export`, display-tag automatically generates this `URL`

```
http://localhost:8084/myaction.action?d-3682230-e=2&6578706f7274=1
```

Answer (score 0):

OGNL only support name’s atributes well formmed in Java and these names cannot start with numbers.

You cannot avoid this warning